# Apply Python function to each row and append

Tags: python, pandas, loops, output, jaro-winkler

I have the following data :

[image]

I am trying to use the library - **pyjarowinkler**
and find the distance between strings - my hello world code works

```
#Hello World
d1=distance.get_jaro_distance("Hello","hello", winkler=True, scaling=0.1);
d1
```

When I try to iterate each row or use apply my code fails. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

```
#Import data 
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')
from pyjarowinkler import distance
score=df.apply(distance.get_jaro_distance(df[S1],df[Stores]))



# iterating over rows using iterrows() function  
for i, j in df.iterrows(): 
    print(i, j,distance.get_jaro_distance(i,j,winkler=True, scaling=0.1)) 
    print()
```

Error:

```
JaroDistanceException: Cannot calculate distance from NoneType (int, Series)
```

The expected output is :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do

```
df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda d: distance.get_jaro_distance(d['S1'],d['store'],winkler=True,scaling=0.1), axis=1)
```

note the `axis=1` parameter being passed to `.apply`, this tells it to operate on the df row-wise rather than column-wise